# reject_if format is not in URL format in Rails 3 nested_attributes

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Hi I am trying to validate `nested_attributes`, to reject if not in proper URL format

Here's my `reject_if` code:

```
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :campaign_posts, :allow_destroy => true, 
                                :reject_if => :bad_uri


  def bad_uri(attribute)
    attribute['post'] =~ URI::regexp(%w(http https))
  end
```

But when I test it, it's not rejecting the bad inputs...

It's still continuing in `update` action in my `campaigns_controller.rb`

Resulting to this kind of error:

```
URI::InvalidURIError (bad URI(is not URI?): ):
  app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:72:in `set_desc_provider_name'
  app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:155:in `block (2 levels) in update'
  app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:144:in `block in update'
  app/controllers/campaigns_controller.rb:142:in `update'
```

It only means that the rejection didn't run well.

PS: I have 2 models Campaign and Campaign Post

**UPDATE**

If URI is not a URI, it's failing in my controller:

```
def get_parsed_data(p)
    # Parse URL
    provider = "http://api.embed.ly/1/oembed?url="
    url = (p.post).to_s
    resp = Net::HTTP.get_response(URI.parse(provider + url))
    data = resp.body
    @result = JSON.parse(data)
end
```

And also, I tried to change the condition to `!=` but it isn't accepting URL inputs too. It's not accepting both NON URLs and URLs

```
def bad_uri(attribute)
  attribute['post'] != URI::regexp(%w(http https))
end
```

Comment: looks quite ok to me. i would write a test case checking that the `reject_if` works properly. what is the code at `campaigns_controller` that raises the error.

Comment: The case now is that it is not accepting non URLs but not accepting also URLs. I changed to `!=` in `attribute['post'] != URI::regexp(%w(http https))` Check my edit about the controller error

Comment: i guess you mean `!~`

Comment: Hi sorry, this one's fixed.

Made it like this instead:

`def bad_uri_or_blank(attribute)
    (attribute['post'] =~ /^(http|https):\/\/[a-z0-9]+([\-\.]{1}[a-z0-9]+)*\.[a-z]{2,5}(([0-9]{1,5})?\/.*)?$/ix) == nil
  end`